# "hg log" command is taking hours instead of seconds on new machine

Tags: mercurial

The Jenkins mercurial plugin runs an `hg log` command at the beginning to determine which commits are new for that build.  Here's an example:  `hg log --template "<changeset node='{node}' author='{author|xmlescape}' rev='{rev}' date='{date}'><msg>{desc|xmlescape}</msg><added>{file_adds|stringify|xmlescape}</added><deleted>{file_dels|stringify|xmlescape}</deleted><files>{files|stringify|xmlescape}</files><parents>{parents}</parents></changeset>\n" --rev pcdmis2015:0 --follow --prune 4e2c98f139772300206e87349c4d7b63e1a17d05 --encoding UTF-8 --encodingmode replace`

On my old, out of warranty win7 machines, this command takes between 20 and 90 seconds to complete, depending on the machine.

But on my new win10 virtual machines, which have shown to be faster in every other regard so far, this same command in the same repository takes about **4.5 hours**.

Why might this be?  What could be happening that takes so long?

Is there any way overcome or ameliorate this problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. It can be different Mercurials (standalone vs "for Pythons")
2. It can be different versions|configurations of Pythons (if used)
3. It can be damaged repo (check `hg verify`)

`hg log --debug --time --profile` will show you main time-eaters (as last resort)

Answer (score 1):

Does you new machine have a virus scanner running?  They intercede in all file access and a log accesses a lot of files.